# PHP text to array and with key

Tags: php, regex, arrays, split

I know RegExp not well, I did not succeeded to split string to array.

I have string like:

```
<h5>some text in header</h5>
some other content, that belongs to header <p> or <a> or <img> inside.. not important...
<h5>Second text header</h5>
```

So What I am trying to do is to split text string into array where KEY would be text from header and CONTENT would be all the rest content till the next header like:

array("some text in header" => "some other content, that belongs to header...", ...)

Comment: Better to use an html-parsing library.

Comment: dont use regex ; instead use dom parser

Comment: I agree. What is the purpose of this? DOMDocument will turn the string into an object that you can easily work with.

Comment: What about embedded headers? h2 in the content of h1?

Comment: Do you need the HTML tags inside the content, or do you need it only as the text?

Comment: `some other contents...` are in `<p>` tag or just text in body

Comment: Is it always one line for header followed by one line for the content?  If so I will write some php & a regex for you, if not you should use the dom parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've used this one and enjoyed it.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

you could do it with a regex as well.

something like this.

```
/<h5>(.*)<\/h5>(.*)<h5>/s
```

but this just finds the first situation. you'll have to cut hte string to get the next one.

any way you cut it, i don't see a one liner for you. sorry.

here's a crummy broken 4 liner.

```
$chunks = explode("<h5>", $html);
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
  list($key, $val) = explode("</h5>", $chunk);
  $res[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the PHP DOM http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php.  You can read / create DOM from a document.

Comment: Isn`t there fast way to get array with regexp?

Comment: you may want to run html tidy on your document before trying to parse it into a DOM

Comment: @Martynas It seems like you may want to go about the problem diferrently.

Comment: I was just thinking about splitting with regexp, so it would be less work

Answer (score 0):

dont parse HTML via `preg_match` 
instead use php Class

### [The DOMDocument class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

#### example:

```
   <?php      
   $html= "<h5>some text in header</h5>
   some other content, that belongs to header <p> or <a> or <img> inside.. not important...
   <h5>Second text header</h5>";
   // a new dom object 
   $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
   // load the html into the object ***/ 
   $dom->loadHTML($html); 
   /*** discard white space ***/ 
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
   $hFive= $dom->getElementsByTagName('h5'); 
   echo $hFive->item(0)->nodeValue; // u can get all h5 data by changing the index
   ?>
```

[Reference](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html)